# Apply commercial license key for iTextSharp

Tags: itext

After purchasing commercial license for iTextSharp (version 5.5.5.0) I received license key along with instructions to download license key library (itestsharp.licensekey.dll). Though, I was not able to find and download this dll, on their official website nor on any other site.

Has anyone had experience with applying commercial license for iTextSharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the link in your documentation, you end up at the page where you can download the .dll:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/license-key-download

Comment: Thank you. Original url from documentation, wich is http://itextsupport.com/download/licensekey.html was previously redirecting to http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java. This page contained iTextCore link which guided to GitHub repo. I was not aware that redirection was updated in the meantime. Thank you one more time, really appreciate it.